# Possible corner case: pandas.read_csv

Tags: python, pandas

Why are all dots stripped from strings that consist of numbers and dots, only when `engine='python'`, and in the face of dtype being defined?

The unexpected behaviour is experienced when processing a csv file that:

- has strings that solely consist of numbers and single dots spread throughout the string
- the read_csv parameters are set: `engine='python'` and `thousands='.'`

Sample of testcode:

```
import pandas as pd  # version 1.5.2
import io

data = """a;b;c\n0000.7995;16.000;0\n3.03.001.00514;0;4.000\n4923.600.041;23.000;131"""

df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep=';', dtype={'a': str}, thousands='.', engine='c')
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep=';', dtype={'a': str}, thousands='.', engine='python')
```

df1 out: col a as desired and expected

```
|    | a              |     b |    c |
|---:|:---------------|------:|-----:|
|  0 | 0000.7995      | 16000 |    0 |
|  1 | 3.03.001.00514 |     0 | 4000 |
|  2 | 4923.600.041   | 23000 |  131 |
```

df2 out: col a not expected

```
|    |           a |     b |    c |
|---:|------------:|------:|-----:|
|  0 |    00007995 | 16000 |    0 |
|  1 | 30300100514 |     0 | 4000 |
|  2 |  4923600041 | 23000 |  131 |
```

Even though `dtype={'a': str}`, it seems that `engine='python'` handles it differently from engine='c'. `dtype={'a': object}` yields the same result.

I have spent quite some time getting to know all settings from the pandas read_csv and I can't see any other option I can set to alter this behaviour.
Is there anything I missed or is this behaviour 'normal'?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug ([was't reported - so I filed it](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/50270)). Was only able to create a clumsy workaround:

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep=';', dtype=str, engine='python')
int_columns = ['b', 'c']
df[int_columns] = df[int_columns].apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('.', '')).astype(int)
```

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0000.7995 | 16000 | 0 |
| 3.03.001.00514 | 0 | 4000 |
| 4923.600.041 | 23000 | 131 |