# csv (;) to excel and back to csv(;), comma disapears

Tags: excel, pandas, csv

This drives me crazy.
I have the following csv file:

```
Short name;Calculation;29221
peter;foster;1,755345
karin;paris;0,2343543
john;dee;0
lisa;long;1,434534
lauren;lovely;0,123124
linda;loss;0,0234
```

I read this file in pandas, print it and everything looks fine in pandas.

Then I write it to an existing excel workbook and the values are partly corrupted.

THis is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw

#öffne csv
QTH = pd.read_csv(r"C:/Users/A692517/PhytonStuff/testCSVtoExcel.csv",sep = ';')#,
                 #  engine = 'python')

for idx, row in QTH.iterrows():
    #c=QoSFTTH[row[2]].at[idx] 
    myString = str(row[2])
    row[2]=myString
    
#ziel workbook
fn="C:/Users/A692517/PhytonStuff/myClist.xlsx"
wb = xw.Book(fn)
ws = wb.sheets["Tabelle1"]
#schreibe QoSFTTH dataframe in zielworkbook
ws["A1"].options(pd.DataFrame, header=1, index=False, expand='table').value = QTH 

wb.save(fn)
wb.close()
```

When I export the Excel result in a new csv(;) you see what I mean:

```
Short name;Calculation;29221,00
peter;foster;1755345,00
karin;paris;0,2343543
john;dee;0,00
lisa;long;1434534,00
lauren;lovely;0,123124
linda;loss;0,0234
```

Comment: I'm assuming the comma in your number column is a decimal point? Try changing it from a comma to a decimal and see if the issue still persists. You may have stumbled on [this bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/50270) with the python engine. Another work around, change the engine to `engine = 'c'`

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately the comma ist a comma for real. The original file is a machine generated csv (;). The point with the engine sounded good, but also does not make a change. In excel the number column from above looks like: 29221,00
1755345,00
0,2343543
0,00
1434534,00
0,123124
0,0234

Comment: Thank you. Changing the engine = 'c' AND defining THOUSANDS)',' is the solution!

'QTH = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/A6xxx7/PhytonStuff/testCSVtoExcel.csv', sep=';', dtype={'a': str}, thousands=',', engine='c')'

Pls. write your answer that I can accept it as solution

Answer (score 0):

You may have stumbled on [a pd.read_csv bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/50270) found via [this stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74716540/possible-corner-case-pandas-read-csv). Change the engine to `engine = c` and try `thousands=','`.

```
pd.read_csv('path', sep=';', thousands=',', engine='c')
```